# Android GestureDetector Swipe Up/Down vs. Left/Right

Tags: android, android-gesture

I'm using GestureDetector to change the view. It works, but how do I make so that it only changes when the user swipes from Left-to-Right or Right-to-Left and not Down-to-Up...
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an existing answer for you. Please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the gesture handling rule to a minimum absolute difference between the X values and a maximum absolute difference between the Y values, you can also add a rule to get the gesture only if the X difference is bigger than the Y difference.